# Gson with static type, or runtime type

Tags: java, json, gson

I am serializing a class from a hierarchy with Gson, and this is my proof-of-concept code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class A {
    public String aField;
}

class B extends A {
    public String bField;
}

class Main {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.aField = "field from a";
        b.bField = "field from b";
        A a = b;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(a));
    }
}
```

with prints out:

```
{"bField":"field from b","aField":"field from a"}
```

So we can see Gson uses the fields from the dynamic type of the object its going to serialize (class B). But. Is there a way to make Gson use the static type of the object (class A)? I want to get someting like

```
{"aField":"field from a"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: yes. Use the `toJson(Object src, Type srcType)` and explicitely specify the type you want. In your case `gson.toJson(a, A.class)`

Comment: as a side note, the object `a` does not hold any knowledge of the declared type `A`.

Comment: I don't really see a duplicate of this question anywhere.  You should expand your comment(s) into an answer @njzk2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @njzk2 posted, I have to use `toJson(Object src, Type srcType)` with A's class like in `gson.toJson(a, A.class)`.

For the other folks who didn't see this little detail like me:

You have to use A.class, and not a.getClass(). the former is an identifier of any class, but the latter returns, as the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) says, the **runtime** class of the object.

Thanks @njzk2.